# Weak*-separability of the unit ball of $X’$ and density characters and cardinalities of $X$ and $X’$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality, preduals

(This question has also been asked on Math StackExchange.)

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $X’$ be its continuous dual such that its unit ball is weak*-separable. I’ve been wondering what can be said about the density characters (which I’ll denote by $d$) and cardinalities of both $X$ and $X’$. Let’s exclude the simplest case that both spaces are norm-separable. And for simplicity let’s assume the generalized continuum hypothesis. Then I can show there are three potential possibilities, two of which I have examples:

1. $d(X) = \aleph_0$, $|X| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $d(X’) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $|X’| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. This happens, for example, when $X = l^1(\mathbb{N})$ and $X’ = l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$;
2. $d(X) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $|X| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $d(X’) = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, $|X’| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. This happens, for example, when $X = l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and $X’ = l^\infty(\mathbb{N})’$ or when $X = l^1(2^{\aleph_0})$ and $X’ = l^\infty(2^{\aleph_0})$;

However, I have been failing to find an example for the third case, which is when $d(X) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $|X| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $d(X’) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $|X’| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. So I’ve been wondering if this case is actually possible. Namely, is it possible for $X’$ to have density character $2^{\aleph_0}$, and its unit ball to be weak*-separable, but $X$ is not separable, assuming the generalized continuum hypothesis if that helps?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the James tree space $JT$ has the property that (1) $JT$ is separable, (2) its dual $JT^*$ is non-separable, and (3) its second dual $JT^{**}$ is isomorphic to $JT\oplus \ell_2(2^{\aleph_0})$ (see e.g. page 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.06286v2). Hence $JT^{**}$ is weak$^*$-separable and its density character is $2^{\aleph_0}$ but its cardinality is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I see. That seems to be right. Thank you for the example! (Though given that the density character of $JT^{**}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, I believe it is automatic that its cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$ as well, since we then have a surjective map from sequences of elements of $2^{\aleph_0}$ onto $JT^{**}$ and the collection of sequences of elements of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is of the cardinality $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: You are right. I miscalculated the cardinality of $\ell_2(2^{\aleph_0})$.